# Can't lock screen any longer, 16.04 Unity

Tags: 16.04, 64-bit, lock-screen

So all the sudden 16.04 removed the "lock" system menu (top right menu button); also "dimmed" from "Brightness & Lock" system settings. Computer no longer displays screen saver. When forced to turn off screen, no passowrd required to reactivate the session.

What gives? How to resolve other than reinstalling 16.04 64-bit?

TIA, John

System settings:
[System settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMfsG.png)

About computer menu:
[Ubuntu Unity menu (top righthand corner) missing "lock" session option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sriIj.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as another user remarked, I solved my problem by running *unity-tweak-tool* and removed check disabling "Desktop Lock". I don't know how this got  disabled in the first place!?!

Comment: Thanks for recording this. Today, by some mechanism unknown, that tickbox also got set on my 16.04 machine. Removing the tick restored the Lock function. Bizarre!

Comment: Interesting that neither you nor I understand what we did to initiate this change... Glad that your situation was resolved.

Comment: Feel odd "accepting" my own solution but as someone else found it useful, I've done so.